# Trigger a Python script to download external data for ArcGIS web application

Tags: python, arcgis-platform, web

I would like to create a very simple web application with ArcGIS. The web application would ask the user to provide the coordinates of a point and as a result the web application would provide  all the POIs (points of interests like parks, restaurants, places of worship, train stations etc) within 2 km from the provided point.

I have a Python script which is able to retrieve data from Google Maps under those circumstances and I would like to use it. The question is: 
- How can I trigger this Python script when a user inputs the coordinates to download the data and show it in the ArcGIS application?

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE! Do you have access to ArcGIS Server? You can deploy the Python script as a Geoprocessing Service and call it from your application via the ArcGIS REST interface.

Comment: This is a nominal capability of ArcGIS Server, and a license violation from Desktop.

Comment: Hi Marcelo, thanks for your quick response. I don't have access to ArcGIS server. I had a look at esri website and my gut feeling is that getting a license for ArcGIS Server is not gonna be cheap at all. I am in the prototype stage so I would not like to spend too much money by now. Any open source alternative to ArcGIS server?. Many thanks!